# javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for local

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I was migrating one of my old legacy applications from one server to another, with a fresh install of Java. We have an email application which reads email from a local email directory and processes it. When I tried to run the application, I was getting this error:

```
sun.cpu.isalist : 
url = local://localhost//home/centos/mail/Maildir
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for local
*** End Main ***
at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:514)
at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:588)
at com.fml.EmailParser.main(EmailParser.java:48)
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for local
Error occured during accessing the mailbox '/home/centos/mail/Maildir'
```

Comment: Is the local provider related to [mbox Store](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/Mbox-Store) that is not included with JavaMail as binary?

Comment: Yes was trying to get mbox store message (local smtp msg box store)

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue as well; I hadn't made any changes to my Java code, so was stumped on why this happened. At any rate, we rolled back to a previous version to resolve the issue. Later, I found an article about the issue and figured I'd share it here in case it helps others:

> I tried putting the javamail.providers file in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib
>
> `vi javamail.providers file"=protocol=local; type=store; class=com.XXX`

Reference:  https://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/348.html

Comment: The referenced website is dead. Do you happen to have a copy or cached version of the page you can share/upload to archive.org?

Comment: I checked in the internet, page is no more available. i don't have any copy.. btw what is your problem may i can help if it is related to above issue

Comment: I'm not having any related issue; I was simply asked for help editing the answer in chat.